# How do I install node from the file "node-v10.15.3.tar.gz"

Tags: software-installation, nodejs

I wanted to download the latest version of nodejs(v10.15.3) but installing with the terminal states "v10.15.2" as the latest which is giving me issues.

Anyway I downloaded the file "node-v10.15.3.tar.gz" from the official node.js websitehttps://nodejs.org/en/. The problem is I don't know how I install this version of node in my machine after I downloaded and extracted the file.

There isn't an apparent installation file and the readme.md file tells me to look at a file "BUILDING.MD" which I did not find in that folder.

Comment: It's a tarball, you expand and follow the instructions usually in the README, or equivalent file, or found on the site where you grabbed it from.  Usually this includes commands `./configure`, `make`, `make install` to compile from source - but it's up to the dev who created the tarball (gzip'd tarball given the name you provide)

Comment: @guiverc the readme refers to a file Build.md which isn't included in the folder

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! I think your looking for `BUILDING.md` the latest version of which can be found [here.](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md)

Answer (score 1):

either download the linux binaries from this page: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Direct link: https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.15.3/node-v10.15.3-linux-x64.tar.xz
Just unpack them

you can also use the official nodesource distro packages using the instructions at https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

which would be my prefered way to achieve this.

Comment: First of all, I am still getting the version v10.15.2. And secondly, my original question was that I am unsure of what to do once I unpack the file that I downloaded from the website. I don't know how to integrate that version of node in my system.